# Urban Airship with Adobe PhoneGap Build

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification, phonegap-build, urbanairship.com

Can I use Urban Airship with Adobe PhoneGap Build. I've read many questions but all seems really out date. Is Urban Airship Push Notification Service supported by PhoneGap Build nowadays. I also saw that in plugins tab there are some push notifications plugins and also there is a place that said Submit Plugin. Can I submit UA Phonegap 3.0 Plugin hosted at Github in that case? I've read Urban Airship documentation but it only talks about using their plugin which is not listed in adobe build.

Thanks you all very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Urban Airship does not provide support for Phonegap Build, though there is a plugin that you can install manually: https://github.com/urbanairship/phonegap-ua-push