# Urban AirShip PhonegapBuild

Tags: android, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I imported the urbanairship plugin in config.xml file:

But, when I build the app in Adobe PhoneGap Build (build.phonegap.com), the follow error is occurring:

BUILD FAILED
/home/ec2-user/android-sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:601: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/project/com.urbanairship.phonegap.PushNotification/google-play-services/custom_rules.xml:6: /home/ec2-user/android-sdk/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Urban Airship does not provide support for Phonegap Build, though there is a plugin that you can install manually:

https://github.com/urbanairship/phonegap-ua-push

[Urban Airship with Adobe PhoneGap Build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26410129/urban-airship-with-adobe-phonegap-build)